# Unexpected arithmetic results using Hashset<long>

Tags: c#

I'm generating three integer sequences that I store in hashsets called `Triangle`, `Pentagon`, `Hexagon`. The sequences themselves are based on a simple arithmetic formula and are monotonically increasing.

I haven't analysed the resulting hashset `Triangle` beyond the third term, because that's where the problems start.

```
    public static long TriPentHex(int n)
    {

        HashSet<long> Triangle = new HashSet<long>();
        List<long> TriList = new List<long>();
        long temp = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            temp = (i * (i + 1)) / 2;
            Triangle.Add(temp);
            TriList.Add(temp);
        }
        HashSet<long> Pentagon = new HashSet<long>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            temp = i * (3 * i - 1) / 2;
            if (temp == 4128501)
                Debug.WriteLine(temp);
            Pentagon.Add(temp);
        }
        HashSet<long> Hexagon = new HashSet<long>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            Hexagon.Add(i * (2 * i - 1));

        Triangle.IntersectWith(Pentagon);
        Triangle.IntersectWith(Hexagon);
        List<long> TriList2 = Triangle.ToList();
        temp = TriList2[2];     // excluding 1 and 40755
        return TriList.IndexOf(temp) + 1;

    }
```

The above code displays some very odd arithmetic behavior:

1. Toggling the input `n` between 500,000 and 1,000,000 changes the 3rd term in the `Triangle` hashset after the intersection methods. Why does this occur is the sequences are monotonically increasing?
2. Oddly the third term in `Triangle` is larger (value 4128501) when n = 1,000,000 and smaller when n = 500,000.
3. Staying with n = 1,000,000, the resulting hashset `Triangle` includes 4128501 even though this value could not have possibly been in the `Pentagon` hashset.
4. Trapping the value 4128501 at the `Pentagon.Add` method, we see it occurs at i = 56751. However, if the value to be added is i*(3*i-1)/2, it's plain to see that the resulting number should be greater than 4128501. Yet, the below is a direct output of the Immediate window:

   ```
   ?i
   567561
   ?i * (3*i-1)
   8257002
   ?i * (3*i-1)/2
   4128501
   ```
5. Lastly, when I use n = 1,000,000, and I try to call either `Pentagon.Max()`, `Triangle.Max()` or `Hexagon.Max()` I get the following message:

   ```
    Hexagon.Max()  This expression causes side effects and will not be evaluate    long
   ```

Would appreciate any help on this very odd problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your `HashSet` stores longs, but you're using ints in your loop bodies for the computation, and you start producing overflows very quickly.

Changing `i` in the for blocks from `int` to `long`, this method retuns 1533776805 for n = 500,000 and n = 1,000,000.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I thought because I was using `int` for counters only (such as `i`) whereas all computation was done in `long` (such as `temp`), I wouldn't have thought that this would be overflow issue.

Comment: The arithmetic is being done solely on integers, and then being assigned to a variable of type long. The compiler doesn't complain about this, because a `long` can hold any `int` value, but the assignment is a separate step from the computation itself.

Comment: I should note that you can change any of the other values involved in the coputation to a literal long and see the same result, i.e. `i * (i + 1L)) / 2L`, for the same reasons.